# VK bot: какой адрес для подтверждения сервера вводить?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, docker, flask, gunicorn

Только начинаю изучать серверную часть, поэтому в вопросе полный "ноль".
Есть сервер на Ubuntu. 
Есть контейнер Docker с образом python 3.6, Flask, Vk_api, redis, gunicorn и самим приложением. 
Контейнер запущен, работает, команда после запуска контейнера:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80", "app:app"]
```

Встал вопрос, какой адрес указывать в настройках сервера панели управления VK для подтверждения Callback-запросов. В docker-compose.yaml в настройках services сейчас прописано `ports: -"127.0.0.1:9000:80"`.
Как теперь локалхост перебросить на IP-шник? Как выделить IP сервера для этого дела? 
Буду благодарна любой помощи.

Comment: https://whatismyipaddress.com твой ip для вк

Comment: @AndrioSkur Локалка находится на удаленном сервере

Comment: ну зайдите туда по `ssh` и команда `curl https://ipinfo.io/ip` вернет вам ip

Comment: @AndrioSkur Айпишник отдает страницу с содержанием "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Comment: то есть когда вы на тот ip который отдал вaм curl делаете запрос он отдает "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." ?

Comment: @AndrioSkur да :(

Comment: сделайте внутри сервера команду `curl localhost:80`

Comment: а также дайте сюда вывод команды `docker ps`(тоже внутри сервера запускать)